# canvas drawImage() render Font Awesome Icon

Tags: javascript, canvas, font-awesome, drawimage

I need to render font awesome image using canvas drawImage(). The drawImage accept image argument:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage#image
> An element to draw into the context. The specification permits any canvas image source, specifically, an HTMLImageElement, an SVGImageElement, an HTMLVideoElement, an HTMLCanvasElement, an ImageBitmap, an OffscreenCanvas, or a VideoFrame.

I found the svg file from Font Awesome repository. For example:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/svgs/solid/calendar.svg

So here is my working code:

```js
const context = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext('2d');

const image = new Image();
image.src = `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/svgs/solid/calendar.svg`;

image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100);
};
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #000000;">
```

But the svg file has a black color with white background. I want to change the color and the background font awesome icon before rendering. How can I do that? Here is my current attempt. Currently it has this error: `DOMException: The source image could not be decoded.` and I don't think my current approach will work anyway...

```js
const context = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext('2d');

modifyAndDraw(
  `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/svgs/solid/calendar.svg`,
  context
);
        
async function modifyAndDraw(iconUrl, ctx) {
  try {
    const svgText = await fetchData(iconUrl);
    const modifiedSvgText = modifySvgContent(svgText, '#ff0000', '#00ff00');
    const imageBitmap = await createImageBitmap(
      new Blob([modifiedSvgText], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' })
    );
    ctx.drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0, 100, 100);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
};

async function fetchData(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to fetch data from ${url}`);
  }
  return response.text();
};

async function modifySvgContent(svgText, fillColor, backgroundColor) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(svgText, 'image/svg+xml');
  const svgElement = xmlDoc.documentElement;

  // Change fill color
  svgElement.querySelectorAll('[fill]').forEach((element) => {
    element.setAttribute('fill', fillColor);
  });

  // Add background color
  svgElement.setAttribute('style', `background-color: ${backgroundColor}`);

  return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);
};
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
    style="border:1px solid #000000;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `createImageBitmap` directly with a Blob containing the modified SVG data should work, but looks like there is some issue with decoding the SVG data when using this method.

You can try using the `Image` object with a data URL to decode and render the SVG data correctly.

```js
const context = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext('2d');

modifyAndDraw(
  `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/svgs/solid/calendar.svg`,
  context
);

async function modifyAndDraw(iconUrl, ctx) {
  try {
    const svgText = await fetchData(iconUrl);
    const modifiedSvgText = modifySvgContent(svgText, '#ff0000', '#00ff00');
    const image = new Image(); // <--- Notice here
    image.src = `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,  ${encodeURIComponent(modifiedSvgText)}`;
    image.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
};

async function fetchData(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to fetch data from ${url}`);
  }
  return response.text();
};

function modifySvgContent(svgText, fillColor, backgroundColor) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(svgText, 'image/svg+xml');
  const svgElement = xmlDoc.documentElement;

  const styleElement = xmlDoc.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'style');
  styleElement.textContent = `path { fill: ${fillColor}; }`;
  svgElement.insertBefore(styleElement, svgElement.firstChild);

  // Add background color
  svgElement.setAttribute('style', `background-color: ${backgroundColor}`);

  return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);
};
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  </canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Font Awesome SVGs don't have any `fill`s specified, so trying to change them won't work.

For a SVG that has a single `<path>`, you can just inject the desired fill color into the text.

```js
const context = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext('2d');

modifyAndDraw(
  `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/svgs/solid/calendar.svg`,
  context
);

async function modifyAndDraw(iconUrl, ctx) {
  const svgText = await fetchData(iconUrl);
  const modifiedSvgText = svgText.replace('<path ', '<path fill="purple" ');
  const blob = new Blob([modifiedSvgText], {
    type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
  });
  const image = await loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100);
};

async function fetchData(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to fetch data from ${url}`);
  }
  return response.text();
};

async function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = () => resolve(img);
  });
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
```

Comment: Ah I see... thanks for your explanation. The source svg doesn't have fill element so it doesn't have any meaning to manipulate it. Thanks a lot!!